# Jquery and ajax to load thumb image into <div>, then reload <div> with bigger image

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery and ajax to load a thumbnail image and text into the DIV of an HTML page. So far the following parts are working.

HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- jQuery library reference. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery/ajax to change content of ARTICLE on the HTML page.  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/test1.js"></script>
    <!-- Reference to the LARGE IMAGE VIEW. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/test2.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>


<div id="links">
    <h1>Select From Below</h1>
    <a href="#" id="link_one">One</a><br />
    <a href="#" id="link_two">Two</a><br />
</div>

<div id="article">
    <p>Text with a DIV of article.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

test1.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "testA.html",
        timeout: 10000,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("<p>Error: " + xhr.status + " - " + error + "</p>");
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#link_one").on("click", function(){
                $("#article").load("testA.html #imgThumb_one");
              });
              $("#link_two").on("click", function(){
                $("#article").load("testA.html #imgThumb_two");
              });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

EXTERNAL file testA.html:

```
<div id="imgThumb_one">
    <a href="#article" id="linkToBig_one">
        <figure> 
            <img src="imageThumb_one.jpg" />
            <figcaption>
                Click for Larger Image
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="imgThumb_two">
    <a href="#article" id="linkToBig_two">
        <figure> 
            <img src="imageThumb_two.jpg" />
            <figcaption>
                Click for Larger Image
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>    
</div>
```

So, at this point the links will load the thumbnail image into DIV with an ID of ARTICLE.  I'm trying to be able to click on the recently loaded thumbnail image (embedded in a FIGURE tag) to view the full sized image using the following code, but nothing happens when I click on the link/image.  As a jquery and ajax newbie I'd really appreciate any help that is offered.  Thank you.

test2.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "testB.html",
        timeout: 10000,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("<p>Error: " + xhr.status + " - " + error + "</p>");
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#linkToBig_one").on('click' function(){
                $("#article").load("testB.html #imgBig_one");
              $("linkToBig_two").on('click' function(){
                $("#article").load("testB.html #imgBig_two");
              });
              });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

EXTERNAL FILE testB.html:

```
<div id="imgBig_one">
    <img src="imageBig_one.jpg" id="big_one" />
</div>
<div id="imgBig_two">
    <img src="imageBig_two.jpg" id="big_two" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make my code work.  The thing was to change the SELECTOR to the parent DIV and to put the "#linkToBIg_One" CHILDSELECTOR after "'click'," like this:

```
  // this loads the large image One into the Article DIV.  
  $("#article").on("click","#linkToBig_one",function(){
    $("#article").load("testB.html #imgBig_one");
  });
```

However, I'll use @eddwinpaz' suggestion and insert the large image like this:

```
  $("#article").on("click","#linkToBig_one",function(){
    $("#imgThumb_one").html('<img src="imageBig_one.jpg" />');
  });
```

Comment: Accept my Question. I got -15 points and I solved the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use .html() remember using absolute path for the image.

```
$("#imgBig_two").html('<img src="imageBig_two.jpg" id="big_two" />');
```

More Documentation about click and what you can do.
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, but I may be missing something.  Your function works when I use it in my test1.js to load the thumbnail image. However, I can't get it to do anything in the test2.js file to load the larger image.  The thumbnail image/link still does nothing.  Sorry for my jquery ignorance.

Comment: try using jQuery $.get() if i were you I would not import a .html but instead creating and destroying a <img> tag when .click() using $("#imgBig_two").html('<img src="imageBig_two.jpg" id="big_two" />');

Comment: Awesome!  Using $("#imgBig_two").html('<img src="imageBig_two.jpg" id="big_two" />'); for loading the large image works perfectly, and I'll use it for that portion.  The reason I was importing HTML was because I wanted to include a lot of markup with the thumbnail image (header, paragraph, links, etc).  Is there a reason I should avoid doing even this? Thank you @eddwinpaz  You've been a great help.

Comment: can you please mark the Answer as good so other people can benefit from it. thanks.